# Problem in C# forms when trying to synchronize the content of two duplicate forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to develop a control which has to be displayed in two screens at once.

This form has a slider, which controls the image zoom and it has a tablelayoutpanel which I use to display information over an image which is painted as a backgroundimage using the Paint event of the maplayout panel.

When I pan the image in one of the two forms, the other form should pan as well.

The behaviour I've developed only updates the other form once I stop moving the mouse even while panning, instead of panning "in real time" like I believe it should.

I am missing something about how winforms work?

The relevant form's code is the following:

```
public partial class ExampleForm : Form
{
    private Point startingPoint = Point.Empty;

    private Point movingPoint = Point.Empty;
    private bool panning = false;

    public ExampleForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        typeof(Panel).InvokeMember("DoubleBuffered",
        BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
        null, tableLayoutPanel1, new object[] { true });
    }

    private void tableLayoutPanel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        panning = false;
    }

    private void tableLayoutPanel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        panning = true;
        startingPoint = new Point(e.Location.X - movingPoint.X,
                                  e.Location.Y - movingPoint.Y);
    }

    private void tableLayoutPanel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (panning)
        {
            int xLocation = e.Location.X;
            if (e.Location.X < 0)
                xLocation = 0;
            if (e.Location.X > tableLayoutPanel1.Width)
                xLocation = tableLayoutPanel1.Width;
            int yLocation = e.Location.Y;
            if (e.Location.Y < 0)
                yLocation = 0;
            if (e.Location.Y > tableLayoutPanel1.Height)
                yLocation = tableLayoutPanel1.Height;
            movingPoint = new Point(xLocation - startingPoint.X,
                                    yLocation - startingPoint.Y);

            tableLayoutPanel1.Invalidate();

            List<ExampleForm> openForms = Application.OpenForms.OfType<ExampleForm>().Where(display => !this.GetHashCode().Equals(display.GetHashCode())).ToList();
            foreach (var mapRunnerDisplay in openForms)
            {
                mapRunnerDisplay.UpdateMapPosition(movingPoint);
            }
        }
    }

    public void UpdateMapPosition(Point point)
    {
        movingPoint = point;

        tableLayoutPanel1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void tableLayoutPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Black);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(tableLayoutPanel1.BackgroundImage, movingPoint);
    }
}
```

Comment: `The behaviour I've developed ...` Please, [show us the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Are you handling an event? Which one?

Comment: Should I provide the whole form code? It is about 340 lines

Comment: You only need to post the code relevant to the question. Ideally, you should build a small example from scratch. You only need two forms with a map drawn on each one to reproduce your problem. As an alternative, you can post relevant chunks of code. This is not ideal, but much better than nothing.

Comment: I've made some edits to show only the relevant code, I'll try to develop a demo

Comment: I've provided a demo that reproduces the behaviour I talk about, with just the code necessary to reproduce the behaviour

Comment: Which is the 2nd Form? and the 2nd TLP? How are they synch'ed? Why `tableLayoutPanel1.Invalidate();` twice?

Comment: @TaW the second form is another openned instance of the ExampleForm. What do you mean by 2nd TLP? They are synch'ed by calling UpdateMapPosition each time the move event is called. The second call to invalidate was a typo, fixed.

Comment: Where does `tableLayoutPanel1.SafeInvoke` come from? I couldn't find this method on MSDN for some reason.

Comment: If both are the same how do they know about each other?? `UpdateMapPosition ` only refers to members of the same form, not the other instance, right? You need to register the forms with each other. The usualy way if in the constructor but as both are the same class it will take some extra logic.. Not hard but for best advice we need to see the code that opens the form(s).- There are a TLP in each instance, no?

Comment: @defaultlocale In one of the last edits I removed it, it's a class I developed for the cases in which you try to manipulate a control in a thread other than the one in which the control was created

Comment: @TaW there's a for-each loop over `Application.OpenForms` in `MouseMove`. I assume that's the link between forms.

Comment: @defaultlocale that's right, are there any other best practices for this? It's the first thing that came to mind when trying to achieve this, other than an event bus.

Comment: @TaW the code that opens the duplicate forms just creates 2 instances of ExampleForm and shows them, nothing shiny there.

Comment: I've failed to reproduce the problem on the simplest example ([see the code](https://gist.github.com/defaultlocale/ed82b06e0ae05217967484e273916066)): just two forms with a synchronized cursor. It would've been great to have a complete example, with designer code and forms initialization.

Comment: how can I provide that? I could create a github repo and post there the code, would that be enough?

Comment: In your demo, can you add the code which enables doublebuffering? I bleieve that is what is causing the behaviour I describe. When I disabled it in my demo, both forms show the point in the same position "in real time"

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but there's not enough space to post this as a comment.

I was not able to reproduce the problem. I've tried to replicate your code as close as possible (with a call to `DoubleBuffered`, table layout panel and padding) and it works for me.

Here's the complete, runnable code example:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class ExampleForm : Form
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Main method (just to run a form)
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new ExampleForm());
    }

    //All the variables
    private Point startingPoint = Point.Empty;
    private Point movingPoint = Point.Empty;
    private bool panning;
    /// <summary>
    /// Main panel. Technically, drawing can be done on the form itself.
    /// Creting a panel to keep it similar with original example
    /// </summary>
    private TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel;

    private ExampleForm()
    {
        InitiailizeComponent();
        //not sure if this one is necessary for example
        //keeping it to keep as close as possible to original code
        typeof(Panel).InvokeMember("DoubleBuffered",
            BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
            null, tableLayoutPanel, new object[] { true });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// For simplicity just a panel, filling a form
    /// Also, event handlers
    /// </summary>
    private void InitiailizeComponent()
    {
        //background image for panel
        var backgroundImage = new Bitmap(10, 10);
        var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(backgroundImage);
        graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, 0, 10,10);

        Load += TableLayoutPanel_Load;
        tableLayoutPanel = new TableLayoutPanel {Dock = DockStyle.Fill, BackgroundImage = backgroundImage};
        tableLayoutPanel.MouseDown += TableLayoutPanel_MouseDown;
        tableLayoutPanel.MouseUp += TableLayoutPanel_MouseUp;
        tableLayoutPanel.MouseMove += TableLayoutPanel_MouseMove;
        tableLayoutPanel.Paint += TableLayoutPanel_Paint;
        Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create another form next to the main form when main form loads
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void TableLayoutPanel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if this is the main form of an application
        if (Application.OpenForms.Count != 1) return;
        //create and show another form
        var another = new ExampleForm
        {
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual, 
            Location = new Point(Location.X + Width, Location.Y)
        };
        another.Show();
    }

    //exact copy
    private void TableLayoutPanel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        panning = false;
    }

    //exact copy
    private void TableLayoutPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        panning = true;
        startingPoint = new Point(e.Location.X - movingPoint.X,
            e.Location.Y - movingPoint.Y);
    }

    //exact copy
    private void TableLayoutPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (panning)
        {
            int xLocation = e.Location.X;
            if (e.Location.X < 0)
                xLocation = 0;
            if (e.Location.X > tableLayoutPanel.Width)
                xLocation = tableLayoutPanel.Width;
            int yLocation = e.Location.Y;
            if (e.Location.Y < 0)
                yLocation = 0;
            if (e.Location.Y > tableLayoutPanel.Height)
                yLocation = tableLayoutPanel.Height;
            movingPoint = new Point(xLocation - startingPoint.X,
                yLocation - startingPoint.Y);

            tableLayoutPanel.Invalidate();

            var openForms = Application.OpenForms.OfType<ExampleForm>().Where(display => !GetHashCode().Equals(display.GetHashCode())).ToList();
            foreach (var mapRunnerDisplay in openForms)
            {
                mapRunnerDisplay.UpdateMapPosition(movingPoint);
            }
        }
    }

    //exact copy
    private void UpdateMapPosition(Point point)
    {
        movingPoint = point;
        tableLayoutPanel.Invalidate();
    }

    //exact copy
    private void TableLayoutPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Black);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(tableLayoutPanel.BackgroundImage, movingPoint);
    }
}
```

And here's the result:

[image: two forms with a red square being dragged]

As you can see, as I'm padding the background image (red square) on one form, it's position is getting updated in another one.

You probably need to:

- run this code and verify that it works for you too;
- figure out what's the difference between your code and this example;
- create a complete, reproducible example of your own.

Some parts of your code are not included in the question. You might want to post:

- contents of `ExampleForm.desinger.cs`, in particularly `InitializeComponents` method;
- a background image of `tableLayoutPanel1`;
- the calling code, that creates multiple instances of `ExampleForm`.

Good luck :)

Comment: This is more useful than you might think, when I find out what is different between what I did and what you've done, I'll post, thanks a lot for your time and implication even with the hurdles I unintentionally set

Comment: @OscarGuillamon Understanding a question is half an answer :) You're welcome!

Comment: Well, I found out what was "wrong" the image I am panning on is a file about 20MB big, which is even bigger when loaded in winforms. This prevents the invalidate from actually firing until I stop moving, moment in which control is restored the the form I intend to synchronize and then, the update is applied. If I instead update the other form every 20 or so move events in the form I am panning, the other form updates as expected.

Comment: @OscarGuillamon I guess, this is a performance issue, redrawing this kind of image takes some time. Perhaps, you can try a completely different approach: load this image on a picturebox, put it in a panel, and then, instead of repainting a panel just move the picturebox.

Comment: should I manipulate the top and left properties of the picturebox in order to achieve the behaviour I desire?

Comment: @OscarGuillamon yes, that's what I'm thinking about.